# What does the phrase んと流す mean?

Tags: grammar

Meaning of んと流す

Could anyone please explain the meaning of 得させんと流す to me?

Full sentence:

> 多くの人の為に、罪の赦しを得させんと流すものなり。
>   http://s.vndb.org/sf/25/36025.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not parsing it correctly. The -n belongs to the previous verb esaseN. It is a contraction of -[mu](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82%93&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=121159900000) > -m > -n. It is meaning #2 expressing intention.

> All of you, drink of this chalice. It is the blood of my contract.
>   It is that which flows in order to receive redemption for the sins of the many.

Comment: In this case, 得る is acting on its own and 赦し is nominalized, right? Tricky to parse!